# retrieve updated table from database - MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to retrieve all the data from a table using just one connection. Here is a pseudo code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,pass,db)
def some_fun():
    global db
    cur=db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TableName")
    result = cur.fetchall()
    for i in result:
        print i
    cur.close()

while True:
    some_fun()
```

This code doesn't work and every times gives the same records as a result even the content of the table has changed.

How can i achieve multiple query with just one single connection and not opening the connection every time i have to get the table contents.

Thanks

Comment: To fetch all data from a table `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TableName")` this part of your code does already. while loop is unnecessary.

Comment: but there is some other code that inserts data into this same table.. so my this while loop fetches me updated table

Answer (score 0):

If your major concern is reusing a conection without closing and opening it repeatedly, you can do something like the following.

The cursor won't close, and every new query will fetch the updated data inside the table.

```
import MySQLdb

class Dbconnect(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dbconection = MySQLdb.connect(host='host', port=int('port'), user='user', passwd'passwd', db='schema_db')
        self.dbcursor = self.dbconection.cursor()


db = Dbconnect()
# conection made before the infinite loop
while True:
    db.dbcursor.execute()
    # use an iterator to view results. This consumes the cursor
    for row in db.dbcursor:
        print row
```